# Nested for loop with if statement and 2-dim array javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find "a" in my 2 diminsional array called arr. Using the if statement if there is an "a" it should set my bol 2 diminsional array to true in the same location where "a" is in my other array arr.

```
var x; 
var y; 
var arr = [
        ["a", "b", "c"],
        ["d", "e", "a"],
        ["1", "2", "3"],
        ["a", "f", "d"]
    ];
var bol = new Array(4).fill(new Array(3).fill(false));
for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y <= 2; y++) {
            if (arr[x][y] == "a") {
                bol[x][y] = true;
            }
        }
    }
console.log(bol);
```

I expect bol to look like this:
bol

```
[[true, false, false],
[false, false, true],
[false, false, false],
[true, false, false]];
```

However in the console bol looks like this:

```
 [true, false, true]
 [true, false, true]
 [true, false, true]
 [true, false, true]
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: `fill` fills the same object reference, if not primitive.

Answer (score 2):

While [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) fills the array with the same object/primitive, you need to create independent arrays.

For example with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and the second parameter for a mapping function which is another `Array.from` method.

```js
var x, 
    y; 
    arr = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "a"], ["1", "2", "3"], ["a", "f", "d"]],
    bol = Array.from({ length: 4 }, _ => Array.from({ length: 3}, _ => false));

for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y <= 2; y++) {
            if (arr[x][y] == "a") {
                bol[x][y] = true;
            }
        }
    }
console.log(bol);
```

Or map the given array and their sub arrays with the wanted check.

```js
var array = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "a"], ["1", "2", "3"], ["a", "f", "d"]],
    bol = array.map(a => a.map(v => v === 'a'));

console.log(bol);
```